# Using the Groovy Method (Jenkinsfile Pipeline)

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

```
def veriableset(){
      def a = "test1"
      def b = "test2"
      def c = "test3"
}
def echomethod(){
      echo a
}
node{
  stage('test'){
      veriableset();
      echomethod();
  }

}
```

I want to call the variable I defined in the method in another method.

I get the following error.

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: a for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:270)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:291)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:295)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.echomethod(WorkflowScript:7)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:12)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
```

What method should I use? Can you help me?

Comment: remove `def` in front of variable declaration: `def a = 'test1'` --> `a = 'test1'`

Comment: as @daggett said, def makes a variable available only in the scope of that method. You can make it a function instead by returning a value and calling it inside the other method.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading up on variable scoping: https://code-maven.com/groovy-variable-scope

The comment to remove def, technically would be fine but beware using global vars everywhere.

Instead you could look at veriableset() returning the variables and passing them into echomethod.